# What part of skill numbers in bestiary entries are actual skill ranks (above all in the case of animals that can be used as Companions and Familiars)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, familiars, animal-companions

This is a question about the sometimes very confusing wording (or maybe "numbering" ?) of bestiary entries.

Preparing a Pathfinder campaign with friends, checking stats for animals that could potentially be useful to my character (Handle Animal is among the skills I spend most skill ranks in).

It is quite an understatement to say that the wording confuses me.

Example with the **Black Bear** :

> **Str** 17, **Dex** 17, **Con** 15, **Int** 2, **Wis** 12, **Cha** 6
>
> **Base Atk** +3; **CMB** +7 (+11 grapple); **CMD 19** (23 vs. trip)
>
> **Feats** Endurance, Run, Skill Focus (Survival)
>
> **Skills** Perception +6, Survival +5, Swim +12; **Racial Modifiers** +4 Swim

Now let's look at the "Skills" part :

- What exactly is taken into account in "Perception +6", "Survival +5" and "Swim +12"? Are these skill ranks, or the sum of skill ranks and other modifiers (from feats, class skill bonuses, race or abilities) ?
- Do any of these numbers count against the limit of extra skill ranks gained by Animal Companions ?

Comment: Which system and edition is this for?

Comment: Based on *bestiary* and *Perception* this seems to be *Pathfinder*, but *Pathfinder* eliminated skill *points* in favor of skill *ranks*, so I'm not entirely sure how to tag this (but it's probably *Pathfinder*). That said, this might be a couple of different questions: *How can determine the manner in which* Bestiary *creatures' skill ranks are spent?* and *How do I spend my animal companion's skill ranks?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly is taken into account in "Perception +6", "Survival +5" and "Swim +12"? Are these skill ranks, or the sum of skill ranks and other modifiers (from feats, class skill bonuses, race or abilities) ?

Those are totals, the sum of ranks, ability scores, class-skill bonuses (+3) and other bonuses, like the racial bonus to swim checks.

> Do any of these numbers count against the limit of extra skill ranks gained by Animal Companions ?

Most animals get 1 skill rank per Hit Die, but those are already calculated in.

For clarification, **Skill Ranks** are what is invested from the points obtained by increasing your character level or a creature's Hit Die (HD), called **Skill Points**.

Perception and Swim are class-skills for all animals, thus the Black Bear automatically gets a +3 if he invested a single skill rank. Perception is based on wisdom (+1), so is Survival, while Swim is based on STR (+3), add the racial of +4 and we get to +7 Swim.

But Survival is not a class skill for animals, the bear got **Skill Focus** on Survival though (+3).

Total without ranks: Perception +4, Survival +4, Swim +10, so the bear has 2 skill ranks in Perception, 1 rank in Survival and 2 in Swim.

Being an animal with 5 HD, the bear has 5 skill points to distribute, which seems to match his skills ranks perfectly.